# Is there a way to use watir to open a link in a new tab or window in firefox

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, firewatir

I have a web application I am automating with watir. The application has a browsing page which shows thumbnails for a set of templates. Each thumbnail is a link to the template. I need to open each template in a new tab or window and take a screen shot or print a pdf of the template to verify that it opens correctly and looks correct. Then close that tab or window and return to the template browser to open the next template. I need to do this on firefox/safari chrome and IE mac and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Why not open it in the same tab, take the sreenshot, then go back?

I haven't used Watir, only Selenium, but it looks like Watir has a `back` method as well. If not, you can probably store the URL of the page with the thumbnails and then open it directly by URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the url of the link, store it in an variable, open a new browser window and then with `ie.goto(url)` you can open the link in a new browser.